# Collecting data from a website using bot ( web harvesting)

Tags: web-scraping, bots

I'm trying to collect data from a website using a bot in order to simulate a real web traffic, is there anyway to collect a stream of data (apache log lines).

Thanks guys, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Can you please explain more, what kind of data are you trying to collect?

Comment: in fact I'm trying to get more log lines, such as apache logs : "127.0.0.1 - frank [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2326", they are generated just by navigating in the wibsite, thats why I'm looking for a robot who navigate in the website randomly

Comment: Oh ok, so you want a bot to navigate your website which will in turn cause apache to create log files? Have you tried building anything yet?

Comment: I've tried an Add-on for firefox and chrome called iMacros here is the link : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/ . but it just repeat in a finite loop a scenario that I've already recorded